# Save and retrieve images and label onto the next view. xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have got a text field, and then I type some text onto it.

I have got a requirement to pass on the text to the next view when I press Done button from the text Field.

This is it, please let me know If I can be more specific.

Comment: LOL wut?  -- I mean, what does your view look like?  Is it a collection of labels, text fields and images or a single something?  To get a good answer, we need more to run with. Screenshots or code or whatever.

Comment: I have edited my question, kindly have a check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done button code

```
- (IBAction)secondview {
    secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    NSLog(@"%@",[textField text]);
    second.string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textField text]];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

In SecondView :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textField.text = string2;
}
```

I think this code will help You...

Answer (score 1):

1)

Set your text field to an IBOutlet in the parent view controller.

2)

Create another UITextField IBOutlet in the second (or child) view controller.  Set it to be a property that can be assigned.

3)

Right after you instantiate and push that next view controller (when the Done button is touched), set the child/second view controller's text field contents to be the contents of the parent view controller's text field.

Comment: I hope with the help of XMLParsing, I can do these linking stuff.